# MOSFET drain current during turn ON time

Tags: mosfet, motor, switches, inverter, converter

In the below picture, once the Vgs is greater than Vth, the current Id starts to increase linearly.
But at the same time, Vds is higher and hence the MOSFET is in saturation region. In saturation region, as per the equation Id=K(Vgs - Vth)^2, the drain current should increase parabolically.
Is my understanding correct or in power mosfets, even during saturation period the drain current increases linearly with respect to gate voltage?
[image]

Comment: Where did this picture come from?

Comment: @BruceAbbott https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/108105066/PDF/L-6(DK)(PE)%20((EE)NPTEL).pdf